# Recursive algorithm to build a tree in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I am doing a crud of functions, using the org chart component of the PrimeNg library to show the data obtained in the form of a tree, from the backend I get an array of objects, in which each object of that array is a node of the tree, each of those nodes has its id and the parent property, to verify if they are children the id of a node must be equal to the parent property to designate it as a child, my problem is in the function of assembling the tree how to make a recursive algorithm So that it goes through all the children of each of the nodes regardless of the number of children that each branch has and thus be able to paint them correctly in the tree, I attach the code (with this code I could already bring the children of a single node).

Greetings.

```js
//Formato de NgPrime para armar un nuevo nodo
    nodo_nuevo = {
        label:'',
        styleClass: 'department-cfo',
        expanded: true,
        data:{name:'',id_nodo:'',padre:''},
        children:[]
    }

    //Ejemplo de datos que llegan desde el backend
    
    this.nodos = {
            Estado: true, //Booleano
            Respuesta: 'ok', //string
            Dato: [
                {
                    id_nodo: 1, //int
                    padre: undefined, //undefined o int
                    funcion: 'funcion 1', //String (nombre de la función)
                    menu: 'menu', //String (titulo de la funcion)
                    permitidos: { pasar_a_manual: true, cancelar: false, estado_servicio: true},
                    id_funcion: 1, //int
                    orden: 1 ,//int
                    principal:true //booleano que identifica si el nodo es principal o no
                }, 
                {
                    id_nodo: 2, //int
                    padre: 1, //undefined o int
                    funcion: 'funcion 2', //String (nombre de la función) lo que hay que mostrar en los recuadros
                    menu: 'menu 2', //String (titulo de la funcion)
                    permitidos: { pasar_a_manual: true, cancelar: false, estado_servicio: true }, //array
                    id_funcion: 2, //int
                    orden: 2, //int
                    principal: false //booleano que identifica si el nodo es principal o no
                },
                {
                    id_nodo: 3, //int
                    padre: 1, //undefined o int
                    funcion: 'funcion 3', //String (nombre de la función) lo que hay que       mostrar en los recuadros
                    menu: 'menu 3', //String (titulo de la funcion)
                    permitidos: { pasar_a_manual: true, cancelar: false, estado_servicio:                       true }, //array
                    id_funcion: 3, //int
                    orden: 3,//int
                    principal: false //booleano que identifica si el nodo es principal o no
                },
                {
                    id_nodo: 4, //int
                    padre: 1, //undefined o int
                    funcion: 'funcion 4', //String (nombre de la función) lo que hay que                         mostrar en los recuadros
                    menu: 'menu 4', //String (titulo de la funcion)
                    permitidos: { pasar_a_manual: true, cancelar: false, estado_servicio:                       true }, //array
                    id_funcion: 4, //int
                    orden: 4 ,//int
                    principal: false //booleano que identifica si el nodo es principal o no
                },
                {
                    id_nodo: 5, //int
                    padre: 4, //undefined o int
                    funcion: 'funcion 5', //String (nombre de la función) lo que hay que                         mostrar en los recuadros
                    menu: 'menu 5', //String (titulo de la funcion)
                    permitidos: { pasar_a_manual: true, cancelar: false, estado_servicio:                       true }, //array
                    id_funcion: 5, //int
                    orden: 5 ,//int
                    principal: false //booleano que identifica si el nodo es principal o no
                },
            ]
        }
    

    //Funcion para convertir el json que me llega al json del arbol de NgPrime

    armarArbol(data){

        
        this.data1 = [];

        data.forEach((elemento,index) => {
            
                this.nodo_nuevo.label = elemento.funcion
                this.nodo_nuevo.data.name = elemento.funcion
                this.nodo_nuevo.data.id_nodo = elemento.id_nodo
                this.nodo_nuevo.data.padre = elemento.padre
                
                //console.log(nodoprincipal)
                
                this.data1.push(this.nodo_nuevo)

                
                //Si el nodo principal tiene hijos
                this.armarHijosArbol(data,this.nodo_nuevo)
                
        });

    }


    //despues pasar aca la funcion para definir los hijos
    armarHijosArbol(datos,dic){
        
        datos.forEach((hijo,index) => {
            
            

            if(dic.data.id_nodo === hijo.padre){
                
                this.limpiarNodo() 
                                
                this.nodo_nuevo.label = hijo.funcion
                this.nodo_nuevo.data.name = hijo.funcion
                this.nodo_nuevo.data.id_nodo = hijo.id_nodo
                this.nodo_nuevo.data.padre = hijo.padre
                
                
                
                this.data1[0].children.push(this.nodo_nuevo)
                
               

            }
             

            
            
        });
        
        
    }

    
    

    limpiarNodo(){
        this.nodo_nuevo = {
            label:'',
            styleClass: 'department-cfo',
            expanded: true,
            data:{name:'',id_nodo:'',padre:''},
            children:[]
        }
    }
```

```css
//Boton editar tag
.btn-editar{
  background-color:#00786a;
}

//boton nuevo tag
.btn-nuevotag{
  color: #00786a;
  font: 120% Roboto;
  font-weight: 500;
  border: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
}


.titulo-tipo-tag{
  font: 140% Roboto;
  font-weight: 500;
}


.titulo-mensajes{
  color: #414141;
  font: 22px Roboto;
  font-weight: 500;
  width: 163px;
}

//item barra
/*.item-barra{
  font: 120% Roboto;
}*/

//Estilos arbol
.company.ui-organizationchart .ui-organizationchart-node-content.ui-person {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0 none;
}

.node-header,.node-content {
  padding: .5em .7em;
}

.node-header {
  background-color: #495ebb;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.node-content {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #404e91;
}

.node-content img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.department-cfo {
  background-color: #7247bc;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.department-coo {
  background-color: #a534b6 !important;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.department-cto {
  background-color: #e9286f !important;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.ui-person .ui-node-toggler {
  color: #495ebb !important;
}

.department-cto .ui-node-toggler {
  color: #8a0a39 !important;
}


.node-parent{
  background-color: #e9286f !important;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}


.boton{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- Graficos de arbol dinamicos -->
                <div class="col-md-8 mt-4">
                    <mat-tab-group>
                        <mat-tab label="Principal">
                            <p-organizationChart [value]="data1" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedNode"
                                (onNodeSelect)="onNodeSelect($event)" (onNodeUnselect)="onNodeUnSelect($event)"
                                styleClass="company">
                                <ng-template let-node pTemplate="person">
                                    <div class="node-header ui-corner-top">{{node.label}}</div>
                                    <div class="node-content">
                                        <div>{{ node.data.name }}</div>
                                    </div>
                                </ng-template>
                                <ng-template let-node pTemplate="department">
                                    {{ node.label }}
                                </ng-template>
                            </p-organizationChart>
                        </mat-tab>


                    </mat-tab-group>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have made the recursive method. please check the below link.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-thnwdk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Below  two functions are main

```
  armarArbol(data) {
      this.data1 = [];
      // executes and set the root element where padre is undefined or null
      const rootIndex = data.findIndex((item) => item.padre === undefined || item.padre === null );
      this.nodo_nuevo.label =  data[rootIndex].funcion;
      this.nodo_nuevo.data.name =  data[rootIndex].funcion;
      this.nodo_nuevo.data.id_nodo =  data[rootIndex].id_nodo;
      this.nodo_nuevo.data.padre =  data[rootIndex].padre;
      this.data1.push(this.nodo_nuevo);
      data.splice(rootIndex, 1);
      // this is the recurrsive method
      this.setChild(+this.nodo_nuevo.data.id_nodo, data,  this.data1[this.data1.length - 1 ].children);

  }

  // sets children in recurrsive way
  private setChild(parentId: number, data: any, currentChild) {
      if ( data.length >  0){
        const filterArray = data.filter((item) =>  +item.padre === +parentId);
        filterArray.forEach((item) => {
           this.limpiarNodo();
            this.nodo_nuevo.label = item.funcion;
            this.nodo_nuevo.data.name = item.funcion;
            this.nodo_nuevo.data.id_nodo = item.id_nodo;
            this.nodo_nuevo.data.padre = item.padre;
            currentChild.push(this.nodo_nuevo);
            this.setChild(+this.nodo_nuevo.data.id_nodo, data, currentChild[currentChild.length -1].children);
        });
      }
  }
```